# method with a return type of "Expression"

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to create a method which returns a lambda expression? I couldn't find any proper examples.

The following syntax doesn't work, of course. It's just to visualize my idea a bit:

```
// Executed code
var filteredList = listWithNames.Where(GetLambdaExpression("Adam"));

// method
public Expression GetLambdaExpression(string name)
{
    return listElement => listElement.Name == name;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create functions which return expressions such as this as a simple example in a predicate builder:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return param => true; }
```

or this expression builder:

```
static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first, Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
        {
                      var map = first.Parameters
                .Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] })
                .ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

             var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);

             return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters);
        }
```

in your example case You should use what Leppie has mentioned below (which I have upvoted)

```
<Func<TypeOflistElement,bool>>
```

Comment: I dont grok what the purpose is of the 1st example. How will you check that name == name? (what the use of `T` there?) Also the second wont compile when passed to `Where`.

Comment: You've been 4 seconds faster. So the accepted answer is yours. :-D

Comment: @leppie: oh, I didn't want to have an expression which checks names in a list of persons, for example. That was just a trivial example to illustrate my problem. Perhps I should have asked for a method which returns ANY lambda expression,

Comment: Courtesy returned :) I didn't realize the question was 'generic'.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Expression<Func<TypeOflistElement,bool>> GetLambdaExpression(string name)
{
    return listElement => listElement.Name == name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return `Func<bool, T>` type like this

```
// Executed code
var filteredList = listWithNames.Where(GetLambdaExpression("Adam"));

// method
public Func<bool, ListElementTypeName> GetLambdaExpression(string name)
{
    return listElement => listElement.Name == name;
}
```

But I can't understand what exactly you are trying to do with it.

Comment: 1. Wrong answer. 2. You type parameter are the wrong way around. Better luck next time!

Comment: My purpose for that is that I've got a huge Linq statement with multiples "Where"s. Depending on a few parameters, which calls this statement, just one expression in a "Where" differs. Instead of reproducing the code of the whole statement I just get the matching expression depending on the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return Func<> since IEnumerable expects one, as in your example it would be:

```
 public Func<String,Bool> (string name){..}
```

Comment: Not needed to use as param for an IEnumerable, but ok, the question was how to return an expression, which I guess I didn't answer

Answer (score 0):

Where method for `IEnumerable<T>` expects delegate for `Func<T, bool>` method, so `GetLambdaExpression()` must return `Func<T, bool>`

Where method for `IQueryable<T>` expects `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, so `GetLambdaExpression()` must return `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.

`Expression` can be converted to delegate by invoking `Compile()` method.